# ¿Como puedo obtener el dato seleccionado de una lista expandible, para luego cargar los hijos?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy realizando una lista expandible, pero no se como traerme el item seleccionado, para así comprobar si este tiene hijos o no, y poder cargarlos desde el servidor. Alguna idea de como implementarlo.

**MainActivity**

```
ArrayList<String> parent;
ArrayList<String> child;
LinkedHashMap<String, String[]> thirdLevelGames = new LinkedHashMap<>();

List<String[]> secondLevel = new ArrayList<>();

List<LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>> data = new ArrayList<>();

//String[] parent = new String[]{};

ThreeLevelListAdapter threeLevelListAdapterAdapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

    parent= new ArrayList<String>();

    Hijos();

    secondLevel.add(blusas);
    secondLevel.add(accesorio);


    thirdLevelBlusas.put(blusas[0], Escote);
    thirdLevelBlusas.put(blusas[1], Larga);
    thirdLevelBlusas.put(blusas[2], Corta);

    thirdLevelAccesorio.put(accesorio[0], Collar);
    thirdLevelAccesorio.put(accesorio[1], Reloj);
    thirdLevelAccesorio.put(accesorio[2], Anillo);
    thirdLevelAccesorio.put(accesorio[3], Pulsera);

    data.add(thirdLevelAccesorio);
    data.add(thirdLevelBlusas);

    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandible_listview);

    threeLevelListAdapterAdapter = new ThreeLevelListAdapter(this, parent, secondLevel, data);

    expandableListView.setAdapter(threeLevelListAdapterAdapter);


    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        int previousGroup = -1;

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (groupPosition != previousGroup)
                expandableListView.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
            previousGroup = groupPosition;
        }
    });


}

public void Hijos() {

    progressDialog.setMessage("Espere...");
    progressDialog.show();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Categorias.DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    try {

                        JSONObject j = new JSONObject(ServerResponse);
                        String returnState = j.getString("returnState");
                        String returnData = j.getString("returnData");

                        JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(returnData);

                        Iterator<String> keys = mainObject.keys();
                        while (keys.hasNext()) {

                            String key = keys.next();
                            Log.i("Parser", "objeto : " + key);
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = mainObject.getJSONObject(key);

                            String cate_name = jsonObject1.getString("cate_name");
                            String cate_id = jsonObject1.getString("cate_shop_id");

                            parent.add(cate_id);

                        }
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+ parent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        threeLevelListAdapterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
            ,
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Verifique su conexion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("id",id);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Creating RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

    // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

}

**Adaptador**

```
public class ThreeLevelListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

ArrayList<String> parentHeaders;
List<String[]> secondLevel;
private Context context;
List<LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>> data;

public ThreeLevelListAdapter(Context context, String[] parent, List<String[]> secondLevel, List<LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>> data) {
    this.context = context;

    this.secondLevel = secondLevel;

    this.data = data;
}

public ThreeLevelListAdapter(MainActivity context, ArrayList<String> parentHeader, List<String[]> secondLevel, List<LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>> data) {
    this.context = context;

    this.parentHeaders=parentHeader;

    this.secondLevel = secondLevel;

    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return parentHeaders.size();

}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {


    // no idea why this code is working

    return 1;

}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {

    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int group, int child) {


    return child;


}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_first, null);
        TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowParentText);
        text.setText(this.parentHeaders.get(groupPosition));

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final SecondLevelExpandableListView secondLevelELV = new SecondLevelExpandableListView(context);

    String[] headers = secondLevel.get(groupPosition);


    List<String[]> childData = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, String[]> secondLevelData=data.get(groupPosition);

    for(String key : secondLevelData.keySet())
    {


        childData.add(secondLevelData.get(key));

    }



    secondLevelELV.setAdapter(new SecondLevelAdapter(context, headers,childData));

    secondLevelELV.setGroupIndicator(null);


    secondLevelELV.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        int previousGroup = -1;

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if(groupPosition != previousGroup)
                secondLevelELV.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
            previousGroup = groupPosition;
        }
    });

    return secondLevelELV;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

[image: id]

Comment: Saludos Maria. Me gustaría ayudarte pero tendras que ser mas especifica en lo que quieres. Para eso tendrás que editar tu pregunta y solo dejar la parte relevante del código a tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola  Einer, la idea es que si selecciono cualquier dato de la lista principal (osea los padres), verifique que si ese dato seleccionado tiene o no hijo.

Comment: La lista se carga desde el servidor?. Es decir es dinámica?. Puedes probar utilizando el id como valor de referencia. Para hacer una consulta en tu servidor y verificar si el id contiene hijos.

Answer (score 0):

intenta colocandole un OnChildClick

```
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
          ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rowParentText)).getText();
          return true;
       }
});
```

Comment: No me muestra nada

Comment: @MariaIsabel si claro colocale un toast `Toast.makeText(Context,((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rowParentText)).getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: ya lo intente así, pero nada sigue sin mostrar nada